# Django: KeyError when creating DB Table from CSV

Tags: python, django, pandas

I need to create a table from a CSV file.

I think I can do it with different libraries, but in this case I've choosen to use `pandas`, as I'll need it more in the near future for some data analysis.

I've a script but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gonzales/Escritorio/virtual_envs/stickers_gallito_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1867
```

Data in Dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3iga509qi8suu9/ubigeo-peru-2018-12-25.csv?dl=0

**script**:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from shop.models import Peru
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


tmp_data=pd.read_csv('static/data/ubigeo-peru-2018-12-25.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8")


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        products = [
            Peru(
                departamento=tmp_data.ix[row]['departamento'],
                provincia=tmp_data.ix[row]['provincia'],
                distrito=tmp_data.ix[row]['distrito'],
            )
            for row in tmp_data['id']
        ]

        Peru.objects.bulk_create(products)
```

**models.py**

```
class Peru(models.Model):
    departamento = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    distrito = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.departamento
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` field looks like an index but starts from 1; when you create the rows you access the dataframe by index by use the `id` field as the index, which yields the error as you're trying to access the 1868th row (which doesn't exist).
I would try:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from shop.models import Peru
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


tmp_data=pd.read_csv('static/data/ubigeo-peru-2018-12-25.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8")


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        products = [
            Peru(
                departamento=row['departamento'],
                provincia=row['provincia'],
                distrito=row['distrito'],
            )
            for index, row in tmp_data.iterrows()
        ]

        Peru.objects.bulk_create(products)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work (and throws an error for the last object) is that `row` is actually the `id` of your data which begins at 1 while you're using it as an index.

Use it like this instead:

```
products = [
        Peru(
            departamento=tmp_data.ix[row-1]['departamento'],
            provincia=tmp_data.ix[row-1]['provincia'],
            distrito=tmp_data.ix[row-1]['distrito'],
        )
        for row in tmp_data['id']
    ]
```

Or you could iterate over the dataframe like the library recommends:

```
products = []
for i, row in tmp_data.iterrows():
    products.append(Peru(
        departamento=row]['departamento'],
        provincia=row['provincia'],
        distrito=row['distrito'],
    ))

Peru.objects.bulk_create(products)
```